# Improving the tesseract detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-tesseract

I tried to extract text from this image using Tesseract.
[image]
The code that I tried:

```py
img = Image.open('downloadedpng.jpeg').convert('L')
ret,img = cv2.threshold(np.array(img), 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

The output that I got:
`re vie`
I've tried erosion and dilation with the below code:

```py
img_erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
```

but I got errors.
Any idea how to properly convert it to string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a black on white text for best results:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img) # <- invert
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im = Image.fromarray(thresh.astype("uint8"))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

[image]